# How to run .exe from C#

Tags: c#, wpf, exe, process.start

I am developing wpf application in C#. I am using grib files in my application. I want to convert this grib file content into csv file. From command prompt I can easily do this. For this in command prompt I need to go to the folder location of degrib.exe i.e. c:\ndfd\degrib\bin. For any other path command will not get executed. I am using the following commands

```
C:\ndfd\degrib\bin\degrib D:\Documents\Pacificwind.grb -C -msg 1 -Csv
C:\ndfd\degrib\bin\degrib D:\Documents\Pacificwind.grb -C -msg all -nMet -Csv
```

The commands get successfully executed. I am able to see generated csv files at C:\ndfd\degrib\bin folder. How should I execute the same command from C#. I have seen different examples but none of them worked for me. Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Comment: Are you sure they didnt work? Or that the files werent where you expected

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work ?

Comment: I'd be tempted to write a Grib parser in .Net. Csv is not an especially desirable format to use as an intermediary. http://www.wmo.int/pages/prog/www/WDM/Guides/Guide-binary-2.html

Comment: or better still, reuse this http://sourceforge.net/projects/gribcs/

Comment: BugFinder you are right. They are working. I was looking at wrong location. Thanks a lot BugFinder.

Comment: Jodrell I also tried a lot to write to grib file. but not able to write it. I then decide to use csv file inside grib to read and write so that project will go ahead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will work, unless the paths you provided are incorrect:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\ndfd\degrib\bin\degrib", 
              @"D:\Documents\Pacificwind.grb -C -msg 1 -Csv");

Process.Start(@"C:\ndfd\degrib\bin\degrib", 
              @"D:\Documents\Pacificwind.grb -C -msg all -nMet -Csv")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class to set the working directory for the application launched.
For example

```
        ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("degrib.exe");
        pInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\ndfd\degrib\bin" 
        pInfo.Arguments = @"D:\Documents\Pacificwind.grb -C -msg 1 -Csv";    
        Process p = Process.Start(pInfo);

        // Are I assume that the second processing need to wait for the first to finish
        p.WaitForExit();

        // Start the second run.....
        pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("degrib.exe");
        pInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\ndfd\degrib\bin" 
        pInfo.Arguments = @"D:\Documents\Pacificwind.grb -C -msg all -nMet -Csv";    
        Process.Start(pInfo);
```

Check also the documentation on [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3s566a.aspx) class and the WaitForExit method

EDIT: I really do not know what it was `degrib`, now I have updated the answer to a reasonable assumption of what you're trying to get. Please let me know if paths and executable name are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to execute your exe file

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exePath + "LSAPP.exe");
```

Comment: Never combine paths with a `+`.

Comment: Use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` for combining paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(...))
    process.WaitForExit(); // You can wait for process to exit or go idle.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Process.Start()` Create an Process object like so
    process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
and create your ProcessStartInfo object

```
startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pathToExecutable, arguments);
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
```

And catch your output using 
`process.OutputDataReceived event`