# How i can run .exe in C# Unity

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I have an xml where I keep the paths of some images and some exe.
I need my program to read the xml and create as many buttons as there are elements, assign each button its image and give it the button to run the .exe

My program reads the xml and creates the buttons. I need the buttons to have the image and when the .exe is run .exe

my class to read xml

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class XmlManager {

    private string xmlPath;

    public XmlManager(string xmlPath) {
        this.xmlPath = xmlPath;

    }
    public Datos ReadXmlTest() {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Datos));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xmlPath);
        Datos data = (Datos)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();

        return data;
    }
}
```

my class to generate buttons and put de image in buttons

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AppLogic : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform layout;

    [SerializeField]
    private Button buttonPrefab;

    private Datos data;

    void Awake() {
        string path = "C:/Users/datos.xml";
        XmlManager xmlMng = new XmlManager(path);

        data = xmlMng.ReadXmlTest();

        foreach (var juego in data.Juegos) {
            Button newButton = Instantiate(buttonPrefab);
            newButton.transform.SetParent(layout);
            newButton.GetComponent<AppButton>();

            Sprite imageSprite = new Sprite();
            Texture2D SpriteTexture = Texture(path);
            imageSprite = Sprite.Create(SpriteTexture, new Rect(0, 0, SpriteTexture.width, SpriteTexture.height), new Vector2(0, 0), 100.0f);
            newButton.image.sprite = imageSprite;


        }
    }

    public Texture2D Texture(string path) {

        Texture2D Texture2D;
        byte[] FileData;

        if (File.Exists(path)) {

            FileData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            Texture2D = new Texture2D(1, 1);

            if (Texture2D.LoadImage(FileData))
                return Texture2D;

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

my xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Datos>
  <dato>

    <play>
      <ruta>D:/exe.exe</ruta>
      <img>C:/png.png</img>
    </play>


    <play>
      <ruta>D:/exe1.exe</ruta>
      <img>C:/png1.png</img>
    </play>

  </dato>
</Datos>
```

My program when creating the buttons is put a default image of unity. I think it's because it reads all the xml and not just an image.

I hope you understand me, I'm Spanish jejeje

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run .exe from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636991/how-to-run-exe-from-c-sharp)

Comment: There are many similar questions on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+run+exe

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a `.exe` from C#, you should use `System.Diagnostics`

With it you can create a new `Process` and fire up the `.exe`

This example is from the msdn documentation

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyProcessSample
{
    class MyProcess
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Process myProcess = new Process();

            try
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();
                // This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
                // Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it 
                // on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it programmatically
                // from this application using the Kill method.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Read about it here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx)